# Ampliar instacia EC2 AWS

Tags: aws, ec2

Necesito ampliar las prestaciones de una instancia EC2 en AWS. El caso es que tengo una instancia t3a.small, y quería "subirla" a t3a.medium. He estado leyendo la documentación, pero no consigo confirmar si la instancia va a seguir funcionando una vez la haya detenido, ampliado, y vuelto a iniciar. Por lo visto es necesario que el volumen sea EBS, la ip elastica... etc. El sistema operativo instalado es un Centos 7.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente necesito saber si se pueden redimensionar las prestaciones de la máquina y luego volver a hacerla funcionar como hasta ahora. Si alguien tiene experiencia o ha tenido que realizar estas ampliaciones. Cualquier información que se necesite, hacedmelo saber. Gracias por la atención prestada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Básicamente necesito saber si se pueden redimensionar las prestaciones de la máquina y luego volver a hacerla funcionar como hasta ahora

Una vez que la instancia esté parada (ojo, parada no es **terminada**, si terminas una instancia no hay vuelta atrás) puedes cambiar el tipo de la instancia por otro distinto según tus necesidades.

Para cambiar el tipo seleccionas la imagen en la consola de AWS, botón derecho del ratón y en el menú *Instance settings* eliges "*Change Instance Type*" y ya ahí te deja elegir el tipo de micro que se va a utilizar a partir de ese momento.

Esta operación la puedes repetir cuantas veces quieras. El único requisito, como he comentado, es que la instancia debe estar parada.

Comment: Perfecto, al final me lancé y he aumentado las prestaciones de la instancia. El tipo era t3a.small y ahora es t3a.medium. Según comentaban en la documentación la única forma de guardar los volúmenes una vez parada la instancia es si es respaldado por EBS. Todo lo necesario lo tenía, pero realmente no sabía si tendría que reinstalar todo. Finalmente no. Muchas gracias por tu comentario eferion, me ha tranquilizado, no sabía si estaba interpretando la documentación correctamente y estaba en duda. Gracias.